# What happened to my answer? No evidence of vote either

Tags: support, specific-question

On Friday, I added an answer to [Copy installation files that Novell Application Launcher uses](https://superuser.com/questions/57130/copy-installation-files-that-novell-application-launcher-uses) on Super User. I also upvoted the question.

Now when I check back today, there is no evidence of either the answer or the upvote.

What is up with that?

EDIT:  In hindsight, I should have looked at my profile, but since the question looked exactly as I remembered it, the user name seemed the same, I just assumed the data had gone missing.  I should have looked further, and seen what Diago saw, that the answer I had posted was still there, but there was a second instance of the question.

Answer (score 7):

It seems your looking at the wrong question. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/55959/install-application-packed-by-snappshot) is the question you answered. It seems like James got cloned, and I am looking into it at the moment.

**Update**

There is now only one user James. Both accounts are unregistered so the user may have accessed the site from two different computers. I merged the newest one with the oldest. The two questions are different and I am therefore not closing either. If the community feels otherwise they are welcome to use their voting powers :)

Comment: That one wasn't on a Friday. BTW your new gravatar is ugly!

Comment: The question he is referring to in the question was posted today. The one I linked to he answered was asked on Friday.

Comment: Bah Humbug. I just don't win. My old gravatar everyone complained I looked like a vampire. My new one no one likes. I am using a picture of my cat or chow next.

Comment: It was asked on Thursday. He answered it yesterday. He says he did it Friday. Maybe he cannot remember correctly, but the one you found does not match his given data. Have I already mentioned that your gravatar... well, it really is.

Comment: I like vampires. I liked your old gravatar :)

Comment: @John. In fitting with the time difference, please note that today is Monday for me, where it is still Sunday for some. Therefore he **could** potentially be right about Friday since the site is using a fixed timezone. *Please note that this is a useless nitpick*

Comment: Today could be Monday or Sunday. Either way yesterday isn't Friday :)

Comment: @John. Fair comment. Would have helped if I looked at his answer. I suspect there is some confusion, but the result would have been similar.

Comment: @Diago: I've got a fine gravatar I'm selling...

Comment: Too bad @geoffc seems to have left the building after posting that question here. (Now *that* should be made impossible if you'd ask me, like a question will disappear unless refreshed every minute for at least one hour ;-) Better yet: show reCAPTCHAs for an hour, to help get that digitising done!) Bottom line: tell us more, @geoffc, was the question we found indeed the one you thought you answered Friday?

Comment: I completely forget when I answered it.  It was some time last week, before the weekend.  Sorry, I usually do not remember that much detail, since the system normally tracks them.

Comment: @arjan: Come on man.  I posted it four hours ago!  At breakfast, then I had to bus it into the city, pretend to do some work, and then look back to see if anything came up.  Give me a break.  :)  Heheh.

Comment: @diago:  Good point about timezones!  Does everyone in the world not live in Eastern?  I mean come on!  :)  Ah the arrogance of the east coasters.  Oh well.  But yes, I thought it was Thursday or Friday, EST or so.

Comment: @Diago: I thought your orginal gravatar was awesome! You look like Steven Segal busting a door down, beating up everyone in the room, and saying stop "Option 1 would have been so much easier." Of course he has the same facial expressions for pain, joy, anger, happy, and stressed too.

Comment: @Troggy agreed, I want Steven Segal back

Comment: Since everyone wanted it back. It's back.

Comment: Congrats to that nice gravatar! Good choice ;)

Comment: @geoffc, I was joking a bit, and it does not really apply to this very question as it seemed to be complete and even kind of urgent if it would have been a bug. But in other situations I dislike it a lot when people just post their question and log off. Here's two examples for whoever feels like helping, as I'm trying to ignore them because (to me) there's no good dialogue with the  questioner: http://superuser.com/questions/54922/install-a-web-certificate-on-an-android-device/ and http://superuser.com/questions/56030/bypassing-routers-dns-settings ... (I know there's no way to avoid this.)

Comment: @Diago Your gravatar will soon become a meme on MSO :). Every time you change it, there's an outcry.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder: Did this coincide with some downtime on Friday?

I recall SO was off the air for maybe a couple of hours, but I don't recall exactly when it happened.

Comment: 7:18 PM PST to 9:43 PM PST  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/10/stack-overflow-outage/

Comment: Thanks John. I was thinking that the missing answer never found it's way into the DB, but if the downtime was caused by a 'melted' router, it doesn't seem likely to be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's the same question? [That user](https://superuser.com/users/14589/james) has only been a member since today, and [the question](https://superuser.com/questions/57130/copy-installation-files-that-novell-application-launcher-uses) has only been asked 9 hours ago.

(My guess, based on absolutely no evidence: the user is banned and tries again...? There's [another recent James](https://superuser.com/users/14341/james) asking similar things as well.)

Comment: Looks like Diago is correct.  It was a duplicate of sorts.  He seems to have cleared it up.